# How to convert sentence into logic formula

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Hi I wanted to know if I have converted this sentence into propositional logic correctly.

This is the sentence

> At least two of the propositions $p$, $q$ and $r$ are true.

and this is my answer

> $(p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r)$

From my understanding, at least two of them have to be true but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct; it's exactly equivalent to the given statement.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the feedback